# How to find a Node in a text file with the most failed payments

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem where i need to find which node has the most “failed payment”  records in a log file. Display the node and number of records in a separate output file. Here is what i have so far. I am new to python and I am having a hard time trying to set this up. Thanks

```
myDict = {}

with open('applog.txt','r') as g, open('output.txt','w') as out:
   for line in g:
        items = line.split("-")
        k, v = items[0], items[2]
```

Sample output would be

```
node 1 904
node 2 967
node 3 768
node 4 895
```

Link for applog.txt: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD7pb.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read from `applog.txt`. Populate your `myDict` and then dumpt it to `output.txt`

```
myDict = {}

with open('applog.txt','r') as g:
   for line in g:
        items = line.split("-")
        k, v = items[0].strip(), items[2].strip() # remove trailing spaces

        if v in 'User Failed Payment': # check your condition
            if k in myDict: # increase count
                myDict[k] += 1
            else:           # initialize count
                myDict[k] = 1

with open('output.txt','w') as out:
    for k,v in myDict.items(): # write to output.txt
        out.write(k+" "+str(v))
        out.write("\n")
```

Comment: `readlines()` is just creating an unnecessary list here. File objects are directly iterable

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.